# Magento: Price, formatted but without currency symbol

Tags: magento

I want to get a formatted price but without the currency symbol and I want use only standard functionality of magento!

```
$product->getFinalPrice(); => 19.9900

Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($product->getFinalPrice(), false); => 19,99 €

Mage::helper('mymodul')->foobar($product->getFinalPrice()); => 19,99
```

How is that possible? (I don't want use str_replace()...)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->format(
    $product->getFinalPrice(), 
    array('display'=>Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL), 
    false
);
```

Comment: The way you call the `format` method (not passing the 3rd argument) wouldn't return the price only, but would wrap that price with a `<span>` element. The OP only wants the price if I understood him correctly.

Comment: You rigth. Code must be Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->format($product->getFinalPrice(), array('display'=>Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL), false);

Answer (score 6):

Just below one line code is needed for that. Try this

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency($_yourPriceToFormat, false, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `directory/currency` model:

```
Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->formatTxt(
    $product->getFinalPrice(),
    array('display' => Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL)
);
```

Comment: You can use the same code for different formattings: just the price (Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL), price with currency symbol (Zend_Currency::USE_SYMBOL), price with short currency name (Zend_Currency::USE_SHORTNAME), price with currency name (Zend_Currency::USE_NAME)

Answer (score 1):

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getFinalPrice(), false, false);
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation of why this would work.

Comment: Changing $product for $_product worked for me, thanks!

Comment: $product or $_product , This is dependent on how you initialise the product Object.