# How to hide currency code in product overview page - Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I am using this function.

```
  <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_minimalPriceTax) ?>
```

I am getting the price like this - € 479,41, from here I need to hide the €. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the price without currency symbol,

```
Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->format(
    $yourprice, 
    array('display'=>Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL), 
    false
);
```

[Source Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270538/magento-price-formated-but-without-currency-symbol)