# i need to remove currency symbol in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

the price must not come with any symbols. How can I remove the currency symbol from price? I want to remove symbols field. But don't know how to do? and I can't even leave it blank
i remove currency symbol in root.xml file. | but that's not working properly

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1 (whole site)

In the `Magento admin -> system -> manage currency -> symbols`, you could change the Currency Symbol to anything else, but can't leave it blank, but after my try, I found we could set it as `&nbsp;`, it is the escaped character of the space, then you could set the price css to fix the extra space width, a little trick :)

### Solution 2

Change the codes in theme files which you are using.

Change `Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(), true, false)` to `Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(), false, false)`

Other codes about price could change to without currency too like above.

If you want whole site without currency, you need change all the price codes appear.

Answer (score 0):

Base on this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7271021/5635098)

```
Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->format(
    $product->getFinalPrice(), 
    array('display'=>Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL), 
    false
);
```

Comment: it is not for entire website. please use this code where you want to remove currency symbol

Comment: any other option bulk remove ..?

Comment: you can use jquery in header or footer to remove currency symbol